# Deployed Node.js app on azure web app using VSTS. After successful deployment, app code file are not available on web app directory structure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Deployed **Node.js** app on azure web app using **VSTS**, status showing successful but code files are not visible if checking through **Kudu** terminal. 
In logs it showing succeeded status. Anyone faced such issue ? Looking for resolution.

Comment: Could you able to view the logs from VSTS? Does that help to troubleshoot further ?

Comment: Are you running from a package (aka [Run-From-Zip](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84))? If you share app name and UTC time of deployment I can take a look.

Comment: How do you deploy node.js app? Can you share the detail build and release log here? (Set system.debug variable to true). You can refer to this article to deploy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/archive/apps/nodejs/quick-to-azure?view=vsts

Comment: @Jayendran : Logs are showing succeeded all the step, and when I am checking web-app via kudu terminal then it is not showing any code deployed on it.

Comment: @DavidEbbo No, I'm trying to deploying using VSTS's Build & Release method. Want to trigger job as soon as any commit happens on repository.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I'll check the provided article and get back to you soon. Thanks.

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I deleted the previous job and followed url posted by you. It worked without any issue. Thanks !!